# Cannot find contact in a fresh channel

Tags: facebook-messenger, amio

We developed our notification bot on a test FB page in [Amio](https://amio.io/). Everything worked fine. We decided to go to production and switched to a production FB page. Now, when we try to send a message we get an error saying the contact is not found. When I turn back to the test channel it works again.

```
{  
    "timestamp": "2018-11-14T11:11:03.859Z", 
    "status": {
        "code": 422,
        "message": "Unprocessable Entity"
    },
    "errors": [{
        "message": "Cannot find contact with id '123456789'.",
        "field": "contact.id",
        "rejected_value": "123456789"
    }]
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The same person has 2 different IDs for every Facebook page (Amio channel). You have to use the `contact.id` of the new channel. If it doesn't help, let me know.